# How to play ringtone selected from RingtonePreference

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I am trying to play a ringtone which is selected from a RingtonePreference. How can I play it?

Here is my xml file code

```
<RingtonePreference
    android:title="Choose Alarm"
    android:key="ringtone"
    android:summary="this is summary"
    ></RingtonePreference>
```

Here is what I am doing in java

```
SharedPreferences getAlarms = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String alarms = getAlarms.getString("ringtone", "default ringtone");
```

When I use toast like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), alarms, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Then it shows this kind of path

```
content://media/internal/audio/media/50
```

But I do not know how to play this one.

Help Please.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
private void alarm(){
    SharedPreferences getAlarms = PreferenceManager.
                                  getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String alarms = getAlarms.getString("ringtone", "default ringtone");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(alarms);
    playSound(this, uri);

    //call mMediaPlayer.stop(); when you want the sound to stop
}


private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private void playSound(Context context, Uri alert) {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
            final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("OOPS");
        }
    }
```

This here should be what you want :) I hope it works

Comment: Thanks SmartLemon. I am calling playSound method in BroadcastReceiver. So it gives me this error when I hover over it "The method playSound(Context, Uri) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (new BroadcastReceiver(){}, Uri)"

Comment: replace this with <ActivityName>.this maybe

Comment: The broadcast receiver takes context and intent as arguments, you need to call playSound() with the context the broadcast receiver is called with.

Comment: Get the base context of the parent class I would think. I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I build a notification using: Notification notification= new Notification.Builder(context). setContentTitle(title+":"+note). setContentText(title). setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher). setContentIntent(contentIntent). setSound(uri).getNotification();

Comment: @FabianCook.I create MediaPlayer in Service class, as I want to use ` mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),uri);, it shows this exception: Unhandled Exceptiom:java.io.IOException`. how can i solveit?

Answer (score 1):

[**Here**](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Dialogs/) is a sample project from Commonsware for the same you can download and check its working.

You can get the Uri from the String that you are getting by using,

```
SharedPreferences getAlarms = PreferenceManager.
                                  getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String alarms = getAlarms.getString("ringtone", "default ringtone");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("alarms");
```

Then you can play the uri using `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: I already checked that project but that is not what I want. All I want is how can I play choosen sound.

Comment: Example of how to do it all is above guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take preferred ringtone from preferences and 
You can easily play the ringtone using RingtoneManager class

```
SharedPreferences getAlarms = PreferenceManager.
                              getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String alarms = getAlarms.getString("ringtone", "default ringtone");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(alarms);

Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
r.play();
```