# System ringtone list in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, ringtone

I am trying to do an app, that lets the user select the ringtone from the **system ringtone list** in *windows phone* to **alert** user when the *Toast notification* coming.

What i confusing is it's possible to show the **system ringtone list** and let the user choose for the purpose of alert notification? What i searching in the website are showing that [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460499/how-to-play-ringtone-selected-from-ringtonepreference) are able to do it `(RingtonePreference)` and about [Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) i only found that is enable users to save an audio file to the **system ringtones list**.

Any help and suggestion will be appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you want is not possible. According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/fa895410-7596-46c5-9fa0-b5cffb987a54/) thread on MSDN it is not possible to get a list of ringtones:

> An app cannot access existing ringtone or alert sounds; however, your app can save a media file to be used as a ringtone...